# Python 2.7 don't have HTTPSHandler and _ssl modules on Centos4.4

Tags: centos, python, openssl

I build Python 2.7 from source code on Centos4.4, but there aren't HTTPSHandler and _ssl modules in Python2.7.10. I have already installed and upgrade openssl and openssl-devel before building Python2.7.10